# Date picker not working in master page attached page same code i use in another application that's working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Date picker not working.. same code i use in another application that's working..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AgentDetails.aspx.cs" 
      Inherits="AgentDetails" MasterPageFile="~/PAPLMasterPage.master" 
      Title="Agent Details" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="comtent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DatePicker/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="DatePicker/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="DatePicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.ui-datepicker {
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#txtDateOfBirth").datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $("#txtNomineeDOB").datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is exactly not working? and post the markup of the txtDateOfBirth and txtNomineeDOB to have more context

Comment: There's two primary reasons why this might not be working. 1. Nowhere in your posted code do the elements with ID txtDateOfBirth or txtNomineeDOB appear. Unless these appear in your Masterpage the datepickers won't work as the selectors "#dxtDateOfBirth" and "txtNomineeDOB" won't match anything. 2. If these elements do exists, for example on the Masterpage, you might be running the script before the document has finished loading. See the document.ready event (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for how to ensure elements are loaded before working with them.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it  myself, in master page control id get changed, so i assign new generated id to control or define Client id in cs page.